# is there a way to remove a substring from all elements in a row within in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, row

I need to remove a substring from all elements in a row within in a dataframe. (All entries are strings)
I could convert the row entries to a list and do string manipulation. What is the more elegant way though?

Eg.

```
Columns                 Row[0]
Q1                      What is your gender? - Selected Choice
Q2                      Which country do you reside?
```

...

Suppose i want to remove ' - Selected Choice' (and keep the text after it)

Comment: show and example of your dataframe

Comment: So the row where column is Q2 is the same?

Comment: yes.. Q2 remains

Comment: see my answer please. Tell me if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.iloc[0]=df.iloc[0].str.replace(' - Selected Choice','').fillna(df.iloc[0])
```

or [`pandas.Series.str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

```
df.iloc[0]=df.iloc[0].str.rstrip(' - Selected Choice').fillna(df.iloc[0])
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by keeping the text after

Comment: I need a example of your dataframe and your expected dataframe output to understand exactly what do you mean

Comment: Okey tomorrow I see it